# 18.04: How to enable wireless connection before login?

Tags: 18.04, wireless

How can I enable wireless connection before login?

I need to be able to login on wireless before login with a user on the machine, since Ubuntu is on a domain and each user has your own login to domain and wireless. I can't login with an user and share the connection with another user and if the second user doesn't login on wireless, Ubuntu can't communicate with domain controller.

Is it possible?

Comment: Because Ubuntu is on a domain and each user has your own login to domain and wireless. I can't login with an user and share the connection with another user and if the second user doesn't login on wireless, Ubuntu can't communicate with domain controller.

Comment: It is possible by using Ctrl+Alt+F3 and working with command line wireless network utils. Look for How to enable wi-fi in terminal and so on.